# What does the /DISALLOWLIB message mean in VC++ linker output?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm in the process of tracking down a linker error with a VC++ 2005 application. When I switch on verbose linker output, I notice a ton of these messages:

Processed /DISALLOWLIB:nafxcwd.lib

What exactly does the /DISALLOWLIB switch mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It stops certain libraries from being used in conjunction with other libraries. For example, the `msvcrtd.lib` library has an entry disallowing `msvcrt.lib` (since putting the debug and release versions of that library in the same executable will cause all sorts of problems).

I'm not sure it's actually a linker switch, though I've never tried it (it's not documented as such in any of the linker versions from the various Visual Studio releases). It *is* possible to insert:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/disallowlib:somelib.lib")
```

in your source files so it's possible the linker may allow it as well. Where you *do* find it is within the libraries. If you execute:

```
dumpbin.exe /rawdata msvcrtd.lib
```

you'll see something like:

```
/disallowlib:libcmt.lib
/disallowlib:libcmtd.lib
/disallowlib:msvcrt.lib
```

in the output, meaning that the "command" is part of the library contents itself.